# Shortcuts in asp.net application is not working using access key properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have write following code for keyboard shortcut in asp.net application but it is not working on keypress.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
        AccessKey="L" 
        AssociatedControlID="button1"
        Text="<u>L</u>ast name: ">
</asp:Label>&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Add New" OnClick="button1_Click" CssClass="btn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

- Access keys and other keyboard shortcuts are not supported on all browsers.
- Some ALT-key sequences might be reserved in the browser. For example, in Internet Explorer, ALT+F opens the File menu. The browser determines whether to give precedence to your ALT-key sequence or to the brower's reserved keys.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178233(v=vs.100).aspx) for more details.